# Complement of a knot complement

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 3d, knot-theory, manifolds-with-boundary

Consider a knot K in the 3-sphere, its knot complement C(K) is obtained by removing a tubular neighborhood of K from the 3-sphere.
What can I say about the complement of C(K) in the 3-sphere? Is it always diffeomorphic to some knot complement C(K')? And if so, is K' unique? I don't expect so, but maybe there's a canonical way to find one representative in the class of knots that can work as K'...

As a trivial example, the Hegaard splitting divides the 3-sphere into two solid tori, glued along their $T^2$ boundary, so K in this case is the unknot and K' too.

Addendum: I think you can prove that K' is the knot obtained from K via a 1-point inversion of the 3-sphere around a point that is not on the knot. Is it known what such an operation does to a knot?

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding your question, but the complement of a complement is the original.  So $S^3-C(K)$  is just the thickened knot $K$.  The trivial knot is the *only* knot which has a complement that is isotopic to a thickened knot, as your example points out.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right, the complement of the complement is just the thickened knot (let's call it N(K) ). But now, is N(K) a knot complement C(K') itself, for some other knot K'? It is a manifold with a 2-torus boundary, so it seems it could be. Moreover, I think one can see that it will have the topology of a knot complement with the inversion argument I used above. My question is, which knot is K', and how is it related to K?

Comment: No, as mentioned in my first comment, the trivial knot is the only knot with a complement that can be viewed as a thickened knot.  All other knots complements have more complexity.  Look at tunnels of knots and tunnel number, which is the thing that will make a Heegard splitting of the knot complement.  It is always a genus two or above for any nontrivial knot. And a thickened knot is a genus one handlebody.